# TSQL Rollup do not reference each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently trying to roll up some data to exported at a later date in to 1 record where the LookUpID for each record is the same

```
application_id  card_holder_name  transaction_id   LookUpID
1060693         Bob               6247460          765858xxxxxx9999_2017
964851          James             6259094          765858xxxxxx9999_2017
937321          Fred              6262332          765858xxxxxx9999_2017
```

In this instance there should be one record but the data for application_id, card_holder_name, transaction_id should be rolled up.  Each element will be separated by a carriage return but still correlate to each other.

E.G.

```
LookUpID               Application_ID        Card_Holder_Name Transaction_ID
765858xxxxxx9999_2017  1060693 964851 937321 Bob James Fred   6247460 6259094 6262332
```

The code below works fine when viewing the application_id but when adding in the card_holder_name and tranaction_id they are not the ones that belong to each other.  I didn't think it was going to be as easy as just duplicating the code which is what I originally did.  Can anyone help please, code shown below.

```
create table #test (application_id int, card_holder_name varchar(50), transaction_id int, LookUpID nvarchar(50))
insert into #test (application_id, card_holder_name, transaction_id, LookUpID)
select 1060693,         'Bob',               6247460,       '765858xxxxxx9999_2017'
union all
select 964851,          'James',             6259094,          '765858xxxxxx9999_2017'
union all
select 937321,          'Fred',              6262332,         '765858xxxxxx9999_2017'

select LookUpID,
  stuff((SELECT distinct CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(application_id as varchar(10))
       FROM #test t2
       where t2.LookUpID = t1.LookUpID 
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') as Application_ID,
 stuff((SELECT distinct CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(transaction_id as varchar(10))
       FROM #test t2
       where t2.LookUpID = t1.LookUpID
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') as Transaction_ID,
  stuff((SELECT distinct CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(card_holder_name as varchar(10))
       FROM #test t2
       where t2.LookUpID = t1.LookUpID 
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') as Card_Holder_Name
  from #test t1 where LookUpID = '765858xxxxxx9999_2017'
group by LookUpID
```

The Results I got were

```
LookUpID              Application_ID        Transaction_ID   Card_Holder_Name       
765858xxxxxx9999_2017 1060693 937231 964851 6247460 6259094 6262332 Bob Fred James
```

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information to help you.   Post the code you tried to include card_holder_name and Transaction_ID, and post what the results were.  I don't know what " they are not the ones that belong to each other" means.

Comment: Have added further information as suggested by Tab

Comment: The code seems to work fine. What exactly is wrong with the result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a leap of faith here but if you mean that you want the order of the concatenated values to be the same for each of the columns, you will need to add an explicit `ORDER BY` clause in each case. However, you will need to remove the `DISTINCT` in order to do so as you cannot `GROUP BY` one column and `ORDER BY` another (the order by column value may exist in more than one group so the order cannot be maintained). So your query would need to be:

```
create table #test (application_id int, card_holder_name varchar(50), transaction_id int, LookUpID nvarchar(50))
insert into #test (application_id, card_holder_name, transaction_id, LookUpID)
select 1060693,         'Bob',               6247460,       '765858xxxxxx9999_2017'
union all
select 964851,          'James',             6259094,          '765858xxxxxx9999_2017'
union all
select 937321,          'Fred',              6262332,         '765858xxxxxx9999_2017'
union all
select 937320,          'Pete',              600,         '765858xxxxxx9998_2017'
union all
select 937322,          'Darren',              601,         '765858xxxxxx9998_2017'

select LookUpID,
stuff((SELECT CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(application_id as varchar(10))
   FROM #test t2
   where t2.LookUpID = t1.LookUpID
   order by application_id 
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') as Application_ID,
stuff((SELECT CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(transaction_id as varchar(10))
   FROM #test t2
   where t2.LookUpID = t1.LookUpID
   order by application_id
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') as Transaction_ID,
stuff((SELECT CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + cast(card_holder_name as varchar(10))
   FROM #test t2
   where t2.LookUpID = t1.LookUpID 
   order by application_id
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') as Card_Holder_Name
from #test t1 
group by LookUpID
```

Comment: Hi strickt01, that is exactly what I wanted, I think its getting a bit late and I wasn't explaining myself very well.  I did try ordering all of the relevant columns by the application_id but I must of been doing something wrong as it kept wanting me to include it in the select....again I must of missed something but very glad of the assist! :)

Comment: You would have needed to include it in the `SELECT` because you had a `DISTINCT` in there - as explained in my answer. Glad to have helped - it's amazing what a fresh pair of eyes can do!